# colorize image where the cursor is hovered

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am trying to make an image card in bootstrap 5. I am making the image black and white through CSS. I want to make a circle colorized where the mouse hovers. I have tried finding it but everyone is doing it on the background image. Like this
[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Yri.png)

I am new so can anyone please help here how it can be done. Thanks